# Cannot connect Elixir nodes on MacBook Pro

Tags: elixir

I can’t seem to connect two nodes on my macbook pro. I am using 
`iex —sname foo` and `iex —sname bar` in two separate terminal sessions and they can’t see each other. I’ve tried setting the firewall and turning it off completely with no luck.

From foo, I am using `Node.self` to see that the full name is `:"foo@ewHBook-Pro"` and then from bar, I’m trying both `Node.connect :"foo@ewHBook-Pro"` and `Node.ping :"foo@ewHBook-Pro"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hostname resolution is a bit tricky on OSX. Try using long names with `--name "foo"`. If that fails, explicitly tell it the hostname you want to use with:

```
--name "foo@`hostname`"
```

The name will then be something like `:"foo@ewHBook-Pro.local"` and you can use that in `Node.connect/1` and `Node.ping/1`.

Comment: Thanks for setting me down the right path. I used `iex —name foo@ewHBook-Pro.local` and `iex —name bar@ewHBook-Pro.local` and then was able to connect with `Node.connect :"foo@ewHBook-Pro.local"`

Answer (score 2):

This is likely an issue in your hosts file. Check out this comment by pma on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3955#issuecomment-156260692).

The solution on the issue was using `iex --sname foo@localhost` and `iex --sname bar@localhost`.

Comment: Thanks @Gazler. I tried using localhost as short name, but it still didn't work. I ended up having to use --name and the full hostname including .local to get it working.

Comment: `iex --sname iggy@localhost` followed by `Node.connect :iggy@localhost` Works on my computer! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

then add a line

```
127.0.0.1    macbook
```

the `macbook` is your computer name.